# Dynamically calling object properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object which is a member of an array called parameters , and the this object has a property called item_ , now if I assign a value to that property , how can I call it ?

```
for(ss=0;ss<=parameters[gpc].children_count-1;ss++)
{
parameters[gpc]['item_'+ss]="hello";
//console.log(parameters[gpc].item_0)

parameters[gpc].message+="\t\t&lt;item value=&quot"+parameters[gpc].item_+ss+"&quot /&gt;"
}
```

I tried eval() but in vain.

Comment: Naturally you'd do it like you're already doing it when you set the value. `parameters[gpc]['item_'+ss]`

Comment: yes i know this already , i wanted to ask how can i use dynamic call using the SS variable like for example if i call parameters[gpc].item_0 , it works !

Comment: Naturally you'd do it like you're already doing it when you set the value. `parameters[gpc]['item_'+ss]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try and access it as associative array value:

```
var x = parameters[gpc]['item_' + ss];
```

Just like you assign the value.

Comment: is this the only way to call a property ?

Comment: I'm guessing you can also use eval. For that you need to come up with a correct string to eval: var str = "var x = parameters[gpc].item_" + ss; and then simply eval it like this: eval(str);

Comment: Try "debugging" teh string you're evalling first. See if the string you get is correct, the syntax is good and if it should work the way you need it to.

Comment: I just tried to simulate the same situation using the same variable names and similar structures. Worked just fine. I'd recommend to find what string you get to eval and try to "execute" it manually.